# Annotation Processor generating files but not able access them in app (mainActivity)

Tags: android, annotations, kotlin

Here is my sample project https://github.com/ilagarwal/uclego where I am generating file using Kotlin annotation.

Annotation name is : `DSLAnnotation`. Is the class annotation and generates another class name Generated$class at path `uclego/uclegodemo/app/build/tmp/kapt/debug/kotlinGenerated/$package/*` .
I have annotated `DSL.kt` in app module with `DSLAnnoation` and generated a file at above path. But while trying to use it in app it says file not found.

There are 4 lib Modules in project which do the following

`processor`: contains annotation processor

`api` : Defines annotation classes

`app` : uses the annotations

`uclego` : Just an intermediately that provides some static methods

Can someone help me with what is going wrong in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the generated file did not have the package name of `app` module. After fixing that by creating same package path in `api` it works great.